# Windows Store Apps - Change Listview horizontal swipe offset

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

The next post describes exactly my problem, but never had a solution.

Has anyone found a way to workaround this?

[Windows 8 - Customizing ListView swipe offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362749/windows-8-customizing-listview-swipe-offset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to roll your own manipulation to replace 'swipe to select.' This framework isn't open source so you may not even have access to modify the built in gestures tied to some controls. 
Anyway I got a sample working for you to demonstrate what you want.
Here goes.

1. Disable the IsSwipeEnabled and roll your own.
2. ListViewItem should handle manipulation.
3. Set the distance you want to activate/deactive the ListViewItem.IsSelected

here's the xaml

```
       <ListView SelectionMode="Multiple"
              IsSwipeEnabled="False">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter ManipulationMode="TranslateX, System"
                                  ManipulationDelta="UIElement_OnManipulationDelta"></ContentPresenter>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListViewItem  ManipulationMode="TranslateX, System"
                       ManipulationDelta="UIElement_OnManipulationDelta">
            <Grid Height="100"
                  Width="200"
                  Background="Blue"></Grid>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem  ManipulationMode="TranslateX, System"
                       ManipulationDelta="UIElement_OnManipulationDelta">
            <Grid Height="100"
                  Width="200"
                  Background="Blue"></Grid>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem  ManipulationMode="TranslateX, System"
                       ManipulationDelta="UIElement_OnManipulationDelta">
            <Grid Height="100"
                  Width="200"
                  Background="Blue"></Grid>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem  ManipulationMode="TranslateX, System"
                       ManipulationDelta="UIElement_OnManipulationDelta">
            <Grid Height="100"
                  Width="200"
                  Background="Blue"></Grid>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

and the code behind

```
        private void UIElement_OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        ListViewItem item = sender as ListViewItem;
        if (item == null) return;
        if (e.Cumulative.Translation.X > 150)
        {
            item.IsSelected = !item.IsSelected;
            e.Complete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Bryan.
The problem is by doing that i lose the vertical scroll and have to handle it in the code behind and i don't want that.
This was one of my first solutions, but controlling the scroll not nativetly is kinda akward.
That's why i need the isSwipeEnabled = true, to be able to register the pointer events in the touch and manipulate the items

Comment: If you want and have the time i can send to you a solution sample so you can understand my problem better

Comment: Sure, go ahead. I didn't test for vertical scrolling and I can try to get it working.

Comment: You can get my sample here:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9542275F70FB9F08%211001

What i'm really trying to achieve is for the canvas to be kept in the same place (it will have an animation on the line) and only the grid moves

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Set ManipulationMode="TranslateX, System" in the XAML. This way you can intercept the X translation but the system will handle the veritcal scroll.
Remove the pointer pressed, pointer release, and pointer moved and replace that with Manipulation Started, Delta, and Completed. The idea is to bind the manipulation to a gesture which is what the manip API will do. The ListView should not have the events either. Place the manipulation delta event in each list view item (GridTemplate).  Check the Advanced Manipulation example from MSDN.

Comment: You kinda saved my life, that set manipulation mode was all that i needed. I wasn't aware i could specify 2 parameters. Thank you very much, will mark your response as the savior :D

Comment: Thanks! I'll update the original answer so anyone viewing this post can see it there.